# Customize Bottom Navigation View

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

I have developed an android application using OpenCV. The user interface has a bottom navigation view. When I pressed items in the Bottom Navigation View it applies different filters to the JavaCameraView in real time.

My problem is that the bottom navigation looks flat. I want to make the items like buttons, elevated from their positions, so they are not in the same plane as the rest of the User Interface.

I am aware of the Bottom sheet, but that won't help me. I have already fully developed the app and finalized the design. I can't use any View other than Bottom Navigation View.

Is there any XML attribute or any method I can use on the BottomNavigationView object to make the Items elevated from their positions?

The navigation view:

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
  android:id="@+id/navigation"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="45dp"
  android:layout_gravity="start"
  app:itemTextColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
  android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
  app:menu="@menu/nav" />
```

The item code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/fiter1" android:title="Filter 1" />
    <item android:id="@+id/filter2" android:title="Filter 2" />
    <item android:id="@+id/filter3" android:title="Filter 3" />
  </menu>
```

Comment: Please, provide some code

Comment: `<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/nav" />` This is the code of the Navigation View

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <item android:id="@+id/fiter1"
            android:title="Filter 1"
            />
        <item android:id="@+id/filter2"
            android:title="Filter 2"
            />
        <item android:id="@+id/filter3"
            android:title="Filter 3"
            />


</menu>`   This is the Item code

Comment: I want to make the items pop out of the screen.. Or in another words i want to make the items look like buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Using Customized class we can Draw Curved custom shapes in Curved Bottom Navigation View. By using Below XML

```
<android.tutorial.curvedbottombar.CurvedBottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/customBottomBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

For Java class is

```
public class CurvedBottomNavigationView extends BottomNavigationView {
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mPaint;


    /** the CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS represent the radius of the fab button */
    public final int CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS = 256 / 3;
    // the coordinates of the first curve
    public Point mFirstCurveStartPoint = new Point();
    public Point mFirstCurveEndPoint = new Point();
    public Point mFirstCurveControlPoint2 = new Point();
    public Point mFirstCurveControlPoint1 = new Point();

    //the coordinates of the second curve
    @SuppressWarnings("FieldCanBeLocal")
    public Point mSecondCurveStartPoint = new Point();
    public Point mSecondCurveEndPoint = new Point();
    public Point mSecondCurveControlPoint1 = new Point();
    public Point mSecondCurveControlPoint2 = new Point();
    public int mNavigationBarWidth;
    public int mNavigationBarHeight;

    public CurvedBottomNavigationView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CurvedBottomNavigationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CurvedBottomNavigationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mPath = new Path();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        // get width and height of navigation bar
        // Navigation bar bounds (width & height)
         mNavigationBarWidth = getWidth();
         mNavigationBarHeight = getHeight();
        // the coordinates (x,y) of the start point before curve
        mFirstCurveStartPoint.set((mNavigationBarWidth / 2) - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 3), 0);
        // the coordinates (x,y) of the end point after curve
        mFirstCurveEndPoint.set(mNavigationBarWidth / 2, CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4));
        // same thing for the second curve
        mSecondCurveStartPoint = mFirstCurveEndPoint;
        mSecondCurveEndPoint.set((mNavigationBarWidth / 2) + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 3), 0);

        // the coordinates (x,y)  of the 1st control point on a cubic curve
        mFirstCurveControlPoint1.set(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4), mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);
        // the coordinates (x,y)  of the 2nd control point on a cubic curve
        mFirstCurveControlPoint2.set(mFirstCurveEndPoint.x - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);

        mSecondCurveControlPoint1.set(mSecondCurveStartPoint.x + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) - CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, mSecondCurveStartPoint.y);
        mSecondCurveControlPoint2.set(mSecondCurveEndPoint.x - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4)), mSecondCurveEndPoint.y);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(0, 0);
        mPath.lineTo(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x, mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);

        mPath.cubicTo(mFirstCurveControlPoint1.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint1.y,
                mFirstCurveControlPoint2.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint2.y,
                mFirstCurveEndPoint.x, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);

        mPath.cubicTo(mSecondCurveControlPoint1.x, mSecondCurveControlPoint1.y,
                mSecondCurveControlPoint2.x, mSecondCurveControlPoint2.y,
                mSecondCurveEndPoint.x, mSecondCurveEndPoint.y);

        mPath.lineTo(mNavigationBarWidth, 0);
        mPath.lineTo(mNavigationBarWidth, mNavigationBarHeight);
        mPath.lineTo(0, mNavigationBarHeight);
        mPath.close();

        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }
}
```

You can Download complete Source Code from [Here](https://www.androidtutorialonline.com/curved-bottom-navigation-view/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As elevation is not supported by menu items, You can design your icons and provide some highlights and shadows as mentioned in android UI guideline so they look little elevated. Refer this andorid guide on how to design menu icons. https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_menu

Check this image for understanding.
[image]